# MATLAB for nonlinear algebraic equations solvers or numerical methods

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-system, algebraic-equations

Which gives much better results while solving system of non linear algebraic equations, fsolve or any other numerical method for example Newton's method? Can you suggest other numerical methods for the same?

Comment: The best algorithm is heavily dependent on the problem, or family of problems, to solve. If you suspect fsolve is not satisfactory or if for some reason you need the best possible algorithm, you should explore the literature for different solvers and make tests. If speed is an issue, you will probably end up implementing these algorithms in a compiled language such as C++.

Comment: Could you give some suggestions regarding other solvers to solve nonlinear algebraic equations or numerical method?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut if speed is an issue and he's not an advanced low-level language programmer, he'd be much better of using what MATLAB or Numpy has instead of implementing his own solver